# Why is a Function.bind shortcut slower than passing arguments?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am currently writing some canvas-stuff and of course I use `window.requestAnimationFrame`. I usually have some global `draw` or `loop` method that calls the appropriate `draw` methods of the objects I want to draw and passes the canvas and context objects to them.

Now I was asking myself (since I have only one object with a draw method) if I could strip away that global `draw` method and pass the Object's draw method directly to `window.requestAnimationFrame`. Of course I had to use `Function.bind` to be able to use `this` properly - also I had to bind `canvas` and `context` as arguments to that shortcut.

Wondering if there was any performance impact [I wrote a test on jsperf](http://jsperf.com/binding-vs-storing-reference).

Turns out that the shortcut method is about 5-7% slower.

Why is that?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but `.bind` has a lot of code to check for a `new` call, to concatenate bound arguments and passed arguments, etc. The [code](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/v8natives.js#1628) is more complicated than your custom function where you've left that all out.